# Is the dark souls pc port better now than it was at it's initial release?

Tags: pc, dark-souls

Basically, I want to play dark souls 1. but I've been told the pc port was garbage. but it was ported to pc 3 years ago? (might be wrong). so to put my question in simple terms; is the pc port of dark souls better integrated to pc now than 3 years ago? or do I have to do extra stuff like mods and whatnot? If so, should I still buy it?

Comment: This depends heavily on your definition of "better".

Comment: Dark Souls is definitely not "garbage" on PC, it just definitely needs a controller for best experience. There's also a very easy to install mod "DSfix" that fixes majority of the issues the port has and makes it better than the console versions due to allowing better graphics and framerates.

Comment: The port is pretty bad on it's own. A mod or two and a controller makes it just fine though.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. **The PC version has been updated at least twice**. The [first patch](https://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791433525619/announcements/detail/206368522048405952) removed Games for Windows Live DRM, the [second one](https://steamcommunity.com/gid/103582791433525619/announcements/detail/204120373994456904) disabled multiplayer region lock and fixed the crash that could occur when opening the Book of Guilty item.